# Interest Calculator truncation error in simple interest calculation (involving DecimalFormat)

Tags: java, floating-point, double

I wrote a program for an academic project that performs a simple interest and a compound interest calculation. The problem I am having is that the simple interest calculated is truncated if the number does not have something other than zero as the "cents" (i.e, it does not show the decimal points -- if the amount is for example 1750.00 it will show up as 1750) even though I used the DecimalFormat on both my methods for compound and simple interest!

I have extensively debugged the project and I am really at a loss as to what the hell is going on.

The relevant excerpt from the program is the following:

```
  double p=1.0; // just some sample values for p, r, and y.
  double r=2.0;
  double y=3.0;
  double calculatedInterest = p + (p*(r/100)*y);
  String output = new String("Computed Simple Interest is: $");
  output = output + new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(calculatedInterest);
  return output;
```

I have the full program here:

http://pastebin.com/sgg0P5ZQ

**[EDIT] Moral of the story**: If you don't read the JavaDoc of a class you are having issues with or don't understand, you are going to have a bad time. The symbolic pattern #.## is not just the universal catch-all for the DecimalFormat, different symbol patterns do different things. In my case, what was necessary was to change the #.## to 0.00 in order to see the decimal numbers that I desired. Much thanks to jpe.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [JavaDoc of DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html). You use a pattern like "#.##". The docs for `#` say that:

```
Symbol  Location    Localized?  Meaning 
#   Number  Yes     Digit, zero shows as absent
```

You should replace your pattern with `0.00`.

Comment: Okay on the table they have for the special pattern symbols, it says "0 - Digit", does that mean instead of #.##, I use 0.00? I'll try that real quick

Comment: I think 0.00 should be good. The pattern #,##0.00 also allows for separators for thousands.